# How to show errorMessage of RequiredFieldValidator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Say I have a code that will force to show the errorMessage of the RequiredFieldValidator.  This validator is declared as follows.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
         ID="valOrderNameRequired" ControlToValidate="OrderName" EnableClientScript="true"
        Enabled="False" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Order Name is required" 
    meta:resourcekey="valOrderNameRequiredResource1" >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The code that will show the errorMessage is as follows:

```
if(Condition true/false){    
    ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("valOrderNameRequired"), true); 
    // code here, show the errorMessage
}else{
}
```

But the code above will only going to display the '*'.  I want to show as well the errorMessage itself "Order Name is required."

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to show the `ErrorMessage` of `RequiredFieldValidator`, you will have to use either `.innerHTML` or `.innerText` properties of the Document Element.

```
if(Condition true/false){    
    ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("valOrderNameRequired"), true); 
    // code here, show the errorMessage
    alert(document.getElementById("valOrderNameRequired").innerHTML);
    alert(document.getElementById("valOrderNameRequired").innerText);
}else{
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: document.getElementById("valOrderNameRequired").innerHTML will alert the "*" and the other one is undefined.  But still it doesn't resolve my concern.  What I want is to show is the ErrorMessage="Order Name is required."

Comment: again it only shows the asterisk (*) but the "ErrorMessage" itself which is "Order Name is required" is not being shown.

Comment: Place a `debugger;` in if condition and check for the options avaliable for `document.getElementById("valOrderNameRequired")`